# How can I put the value of drop-down in formula?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, calculation

I'm beginner in JavaScript. I try and search a lot for making calculator which is include drop-down button. My problem is in taking the value of drop-down button and put it in formula. I feel confused, is there anyone knows that what should I do?!
This code contains 5 different fields and a dropdown button which user chooses all of them, and I want to write calculator with this 6 variables. Finally I want to print 'total'.
I should mentioned that I wrote the code in Farsi language.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>

<form name="form1" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();return displayResult();">

<p style="font-family:calibri">طول اتاق<b></b><input type="decimal" id="assign1" placeholder="متر" value="" name="onlynumbers" required><span class="required">*</span></p>

<p style="font-family:calibri">عرض اتاق<b></b><input type="decimal" id="assign2" placeholder=" متر" value="" name="onlynumbers"  required><span class="required">*</span></p>

<p style="font-family:calibri">ارتفاع اتاق <b></b><input type="decimal" id="assign3" placeholder="متر" value="" name="onlynumbers" required><span class="required">*</span></p>


<p style="font-family:calibri">تعداد پنجره ها <b></b><input type="number" id="assign4"  value="" name="onlynumbers"  required><span class="required">*</span></p>

<p style="font-family:calibri">تعداد درها <b></b><input type="number" id="assign5"  value="" name="onlynumbers"  required><span class="required">*</span></p>

 <select id="SelectPaint" onchange="calculator()">
  <option value="8">رنگ اکریلیک طلایی</option>
  <option value="8">رنگ اکریلیک متالیک صدفی</option>
  <option value="13">رنگ اکریلیک مات  </option>
  <option value="14">رنگ اکریلیک نیم براق   </option>
  <option value="13">رنگ اکریلیک براق</option>
  <option value="10">رنگ اکریلیک آستری</option>
  <option value="12">مادر رنگ اکریلیک</option>
 </select>


  <p>
    <button> <p style="font-family:calibri"> <font size="5"> محاسبه رنگ موردنیاز </font> </p></button>
    <input type="reset" value="↺">

  </p>
</form>

<div id="total"></div>
</body>
```

JS code:

```
function displayResult() {
  var result = calculator();
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML =Math.round(result);
  return false;
}


function calculator() {
  var grade1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('assign1').value * 1);
  var grade2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('assign2').value * 1);
  var grade3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('assign3').value * 1);
  var grade4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('assign4').value * 1);
  var grade5 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('assign5').value * 1);
  var grade6 = document.getElementById("SelectPaint").value;;
    }
  var total = ((2*((grade1 * grade3)+(grade2 * grade3)))+(grade1 * grade2)-(grade4*1.5*1.5)-(grade5*1*2.0))/grade6 ;
  return total;
}




</script>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You should add the dropdown code

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thanks for your clarification.

Comment: You added it in the comment before and I added it to the question so everyone can understand what "Selectpaint" refers to

Answer (score 0):

The question is not good understandable; anyway if you need to pass the value of the selected dropdown option to the calculator function in order to get a value and then print it in the `<div id="total"></div>`, you should try to change those two function:

```
function onDropdownChange(event) {
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = calculator(event.target.value);
}

function calculator(grade6) {
   var grade1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('assign1').value);
   var grade2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('assign2').value);
   var grade3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('assign3').value);
   var grade4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('assign4').value);
   var grade5 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('assign5').value);
   var total = ((2*((grade1 * grade3)+(grade2 * grade3)))+(grade1 * grade2)-(grade4*1.5*1.5)-(grade5*1*2.0))/grade6;
   return total;
}
```

And you can delete the `applyFormula` one.

Comment: I edited my question and put all codes in it to make it understandable. I changed functions that you have mentioned but it doesn't work yet. I want to use the value of drop-down button as grade6 in formula?

Comment: If you go on changing the question code there's no way that my answer can work!
You removed `onDropdownChange` function as the listener that trigger that function.
In the new js code you posted there are two functions and you aren't using them because the form doesn't has a submit input.
Try adding a `<input type="submit" value="calc">` inside the `<form></form>`